# What will happen first - work goes back to working from office or international flights reestablished? (Covid-19)

Tags: covid-19

I live and work as a programmer in Australia and my partner lives in New Zealand.

With the borders closing off and my company working from home anyway, I decided to fly to New Zealand to be with my partner. My manager approved it and is generally considerate.

The future is unpredictable and there are risks associated with this move though. One thing that can happen is that sometime in the future the company will go back to working in the office, but the flights / borders will stay closed for a long time afterwards (month or more). Consideration from manager runs out and I get fired.

I know nobody knows, but I'd still like to ask what you think is the likelihood of this scenario. Don't answer specifically for Australia, but for countries generally.

Comment: I'm sure you will have legal recourse since you would be legally incapable of completing your job in that scenario.

Comment: I don't think anyone here is able to give you any indication what will happen first. There is no legal requirement to work from home, all at any stage they can decide to start working back in the office. Your manager approved the leave knowing the borders closing was a potential outcome.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because we cannot predict how the ongoing COVID-19 situation will develop. Please check the [tour] and [help] on how to phrase a practical question that *can* be answered here.

Comment: You should make every effort to do what you can. Australia is probably heading into a recession, and redundancies are possible. It's not likely you'll have much in the way of legal recourse.

Comment: From the border closure announcement: "Anyone who is not a citizen, resident, or close family member of a citizen or resident, will be denied entry to Australia." So, if you're a citizen or resident, you can return. Whether there will be any flights between New Zealand and Australia is another question that cannot be answered here.

Comment: "My manager approved it and is generally considerate." Did you make this request in writing? Do you have the response in writing as well?

Comment: NZ has closed it's borders to all non residents, so you won't be flying anyway.

Comment: note, you colud ask on meta [about your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274518/165773) without using a sock puppet account [to do that](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6664/168)

Comment: @gnat that was apparently just a shit disturber.

Answer (score 2):

**Flights will likely return well before employees are required to be in the office**

Employees being at home has coincided with a number of things, most significantly, schools closing and parents needing to be home to look after their kids. Work from home is only going to be scaled back once schools go back and they aren't exactly institutions which are easy to restart.

Answer (score 1):

Your manager approved the travel to New Zealand, and you're capable of working from New Zealand remotely as you have been, so I would find it incredibly unlikely (and possibly illegal) that you'd be fired if you were unable to come home because of border closures, yet still able to work as normal from NZ.

If that situation *did* happen, then you should just make your manager aware ASAP, explain the difficulties, and ask him to advise on the best course of action. It will almost certainly be "carry on working from NZ".